# JavaScript problem converting strings inside object (inside loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, joomla, owl-carousel

While building a carousel module for Joomla I am having 2 JavaScript issues I can't get fixed. I've been trying for 2 days. Hopefully someone here can point out what I am doing wrong.

1. I can't **get a boolean from a string** `"0"` or string `"1"`
2. And I can't `JSON.parse()` to **convert an object string to a JavaScript object**

**The situation:**

To be able to have multiple instances on 1 page I am passing each modules individual settings (via php) to 1 object in my javascript file. Each module is 1 key value pair inside the object, the value being its own settings object. Basicly, this is how the JS recieves it:

```
const moduleSettings = {
    "103":{"items":3,"margin":5,"loop":"1","center":"0","responsive":"{0:{items:1}}"},
    "105":{"items":3,"margin":5,"loop":"0","center":"1","responsive":"{0:{items:2}}"}
};
```

Next I need to loop over each module to initialize the settings. This is done on ready using jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // Loop over each module
    const modules = Object.keys(moduleSettings);
    for (const id of modules) {
    
        const target = "carousel-" + id;
        const params = moduleSettings[id];

        // Callback to evaluate true/false params
        function eval(singleParam) {
            return params[singleParam] === "1";
        };

        // Initialize carousel
        jQuery(target).owlCarousel({
            items: params.items,
            margin: params.margin,
            loop: eval("loop"),
            center: eval("center"),
            responsive: JSON.parse(params.responsive)
        });

    };

});
```

The carousel properties `items` & `margin` are numbers. No problem there, but these are recieved as numbers from the start.

**The problem:**

1. The properties `loop` & `center` should return a boolean, based on the callback function `eval()`. But they just return the string `"0"` or `"1"`.
2. The property `responsive` should return an object. But this still remains a string object `"{...}"`.

**The console error:**

The first problem above does not block functionallity. It works, but I want to understand why my values are not booleans.

The second problem however causes console error and make the carousel not work. This is only IF responsive is not an empty string. When responsive is an empty string, it works. But I need the responsive setting.

[image]

I've been looking for the cause of this issue for 2 days now. It's getting frustrating. Any pointers would be most helpfull. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show `eval()` is not working.

Comment: `!!+"0"` or !!+"1" will convert strings "0" and "1" to boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `eval` function use can you below

```
       jQuery(target).owlCarousel({
            items: params.items,
            margin: params.margin,
            loop: !!params.loop,
            center: !!params.center,
            responsive: JSON.parse(params.responsive)
        });
```

For the second issue, you need to change the structure from your server side code to generate this module settings JSON. The responsive object is not a proper JSON. its should be like

`responsive: {items:1}` or `responsive: [{items:1}]`

If you can post that code then I can tell you the change need to made there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. No need for the callback makes for a more concise code. :)

Comment: Indeed the problem is how my JSON is passed from backend. I changed the text inside the field in backend from `{0: {items: 1}}` to `{"0": {"items": "0"}}` and suddenly everything works fine. Now I only have to figure out to keep the code in the form field as simple as `0: {items: 1}, 400: {items: 2}`, not needing " and outer curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've provided, you're not evaluating the params field by name provided as a `singleParam` argument, but the actual `params.singleParam` field, which is `undefined`. To fetch field by it's name use brackets syntax: `params[singleParam]`.

Comment: Hah.. It was in brackets before. I changed it in example but will change it back. Thanks :)